# Creating a multi-Dimensional array of text (Is it possible?)

Tags: c, arrays, text

How can you create a multi-Dimensional array of text? But before that, is such a thing even possible?

I was trying to create a program menu that works with the arrow keys. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    char menitem[3][32];
    menitem[1][0] = "Option 1 ";
    menitem[2][0] = "Option 2 ";
    menitem[3][0] = "Option 3 ";
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s", menitem[1], menitem[2], menitem[3]);
}
```

(I know. It's no done yet.) I keep getting errors like:

```
[Warning] assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

Why is this so? (I'm using DevC++). Thanks in advance!

Extra info:

I use (i): menitem[i][32]

The 32 is the actual size allocation for the text. I would use the [i] as a subscript/index so that I can easily manipulate it instead of having to create multiple conditions.

Comment: `char menitem[3][32];` means you defined three character arraies, `menitem[0]`, `menitem[1]`, `menitem[2]`, each could has 32 character in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it on initialize:

```
char menuitem[][32]={{"option 1 "},{"option 2 "}, {"option 3 "}};
```

or

```
  char menuitem[3][32]; 
  strcpy(menuitem[0],"Option 1");
  strcpy(menuitem[1],"Option 2");
  strcpy(menuitem[2],"Option 3");
```

another option is to declare menuitem as array of pointers

```
  char *menuitem[3]; 

  menuitem[0]="Option 1";
  menuitem[1]="Option 2";
  menuitem[2]="Option 3";
```

But in this case the memory is not continuous, and second dimension is not 32, but the length of the string you assigning +1 cell for '\0'

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    char menitem[3][32];
    menitem[0] = "Option 1 ";
    menitem[1] = "Option 2 ";
    menitem[2] = "Option 3 ";
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s", menitem[0], menitem[1], menitem[2]);
}
```

Because, in a 2-d array, using 2 indexes will represent a char and that is why you get the error

Comment: It gives me this: [Error] incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[32]' from type 'char *'

Answer (score 0):

Just one question!

You have declared Char multi dimensional array as

char menitem[3][32];

And trying to assign as below,

```
menitem[1][0] = "Option 1 ";
menitem[2][0] = "Option 2 ";
menitem[3][0] = "Option 3 ";
```

As array dimension is [3] (i.e, [0],[1],[2]) but you are accessing menitem[3]!! Does this work??